# Adding spacing between dropdown items in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

My problem is in accessing `container` property of `DropDown`, which is a `GridLayout` by default and contains it's children.

Simple app:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        dropdown = DropDown()

        for i in range(3):
            dropdown.add_widget(Button(
                text=str(i),
                size_hint_y=None
            )) # add 3 buttons to dropdown

        dropdown.container.bind(spacing=8) # this line does not work

        dropdown_button = Button(size_hint_y=.2, text='Open DropDown')
        dropdown_button.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)

        root.add_widget(dropdown_button)
        root.add_widget(Label()) # empty space under button
        return root

TestApp().run()
```

I tried using `bind` method for this, but there is no result. No indentation is set. I also would like to see the solution in kivy language because I want to use `dp()` function for setting spacing and it's not very convenient to pass the parameter to python file for this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead using `bind` you should just set the value directly:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        dropdown = DropDown()

        for i in range(3):
            dropdown.add_widget(Button(
                text=str(i),
                size_hint_y=None
            )) # add 3 buttons to dropdown

        dropdown.container.spacing = 10
        dropdown.container.padding = (0, 10, 0, 0)

        dropdown_button = Button(size_hint_y=.2, text='Open DropDown')
        dropdown_button.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)

        root.add_widget(dropdown_button)
        root.add_widget(Widget()) # empty space under button
        return root

TestApp().run()
```

Using a custom container class is not supported directly. You can do it like this, but its hacky and ugly:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<MyContainer>:
    # copied from kivy.uix.dropdown._grid_kv
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_size[1]
    cols: 1
    # custom settings
    spacing: 10
    padding: (0, 10, 0, 0)
''')

class MyContainer(GridLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        container = MyContainer()
        dropdown = DropDown(container=container)
        super(DropDown, dropdown).add_widget(container)
        dropdown.on_container(dropdown, container)

        for i in range(3):
            dropdown.add_widget(Button(
                text=str(i),
                size_hint_y=None
            )) # add 3 buttons to dropdown

        dropdown_button = Button(size_hint_y=.2, text='Open DropDown')
        dropdown_button.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)

        root.add_widget(dropdown_button)
        root.add_widget(Widget()) # empty space under button
        return root

TestApp().run()
```

So I'd say it'd more clean to make custom spacing class as a subclass of Widget to fill space between buttons:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<DropDownSpacing>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 20
''')

class DropDownSpacing(Widget):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        dropdown = DropDown()

        for i in range(3):
            dropdown.add_widget(DropDownSpacing())

            dropdown.add_widget(Button(
                text=str(i),
                size_hint_y=None
            )) # add 3 buttons to dropdown

        dropdown_button = Button(size_hint_y=.2, text='Open DropDown')
        dropdown_button.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)

        root.add_widget(dropdown_button)
        root.add_widget(Widget()) # empty space under button
        return root

TestApp().run()
```

This is the same you're doing in your main `BoxLayout`, except I prefer to use `Widget` class directly instead of `Label` with no text.